# R Convert list to matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix from a set of list of characters as follows:

```
list <- list("0010","0110","1000")
```

I would like to convert this to a matrix with 4 columns (for each of each character of each element of the list) and 3 rows like:

[image]

And now I need the numbers (0s and 1s) to be recognized as numbers.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT with the output of my data, I can see now why I got that error. By the way, thank you so much for providing the answers. It looks like when using the scan function it added the name of the file as well to the list (I don't know how to fix this:

[image: first element]

[image: second element]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, it's not quite clear if you actually mean to use a list or a vector; also, I would avoid naming variables the same as function names like `list`. Here's how you can solve:

```r
# Try it with l as a list
l <- list("0010","0110","1000")
t(sapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, '')))))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    0    1    0
#> [2,]    0    1    1    0
#> [3,]    1    0    0    0
# Try it with l as a vector
l <- c("0010","0110","1000")
t(sapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, '')))))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> 0010    0    0    1    0
#> 0110    0    1    1    0
#> 1000    1    0    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

#### Explanation

`sapply(x, fun)` applies function `fun` to every element of `x`. So,

```r
sapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ''))))
```

takes every element of `l`, uses `strsplit(x, '')` to get every individual character from that element (each `"0"` or `"1"`), then we must `unlist()` because `strsplit()` returns a list, wrap in `as.numeric()` since you want numbers, and we have to wrap all of that in `t()` since when `sapply()` returns a matrix, it does it by column.

#### Update

From your updated question, it appears that your list elements are not in character form at all. In that case, I would follow the advice of a now deleted answer and use `Reduce()` and `rbind()`

```r
l <- list('digist/test_digits/0_0.txt' = c(0, 0, 1, 0),
          'digist/test_digits/0_1.txt' = c(0, 1, 1, 0),
          'digist/test_digits/1_1.txt' = c(1, 0, 0, 0))
l
#> $`digist/test_digits/0_0.txt`
#> [1] 0 0 1 0
#> 
#> $`digist/test_digits/0_1.txt`
#> [1] 0 1 1 0
#> 
#> $`digist/test_digits/1_1.txt`
#> [1] 1 0 0 0
Reduce('rbind', l)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> init    0    0    1    0
#>         0    1    1    0
#>         1    0    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, it's a list what I have at the moment.
Using your code I get this error:
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-character argument

Comment: @Johnny No problem, it turns out to work for either a list or a vector. If you're getting that error, there's some difference in the way your actual data is structured to the example data you've posted in your question -- there is at least one element that is not actually a character. So, try posting your data via editing your question to include the output of `dput(your_data)`

Comment: Thank you so much, and thank you for the "dput". I didn't know this existed (I am new to r).
I added the output of my data. I can see that the file name is there as a string. I only want the numbers (they are 1024 each of them). So at the end I will have a matrix with 1024 columns and n observations

Comment: @Johnny See my updated answer. You're welcome for pointing you to `dput()`. Also, for future reference, when posting the output of `dput()` for Stack Overflow, just copy and paste it rather than posing an image -- it's much easier for answerers to use. Cheers!

Comment: I think it worked, I ran it for the first two elements of the list and I got a matrix dim(m) = 2 1024

Thank you so much! I will do some research for the Reduce function to see how exactly works

Comment: @Johnny No problem, glad it helped!